# Redirect to form with input value from previous form in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm working with Form in Laravel. In that form have a modal that containts another form.
Here's the screenshot of the Form :
[SS1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vHYN.png) ***(I can't post an image because my reputation is not enough)***

when I click on New button (besides of Customer Name input text) there will be a modal that containts form to input new customers and new unit. Here's the screenshot of the modal :
[SS2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c67fg.png)

and the idea is,after I complete the input of new customer and unit, the data i've inputted will automatically input the main form.

and this is what I've done so far :

```js
$("#main_form2").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  value = $(this).serialize();
  alert(value);
  
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: {
      'value': value
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#customer_id').val(data.customer_id)
      $('#customer_name').val(data.customer_name)
      $('#customer_pic').val(data.customer_pic)
      $('#unit_province').val(data.customer_province)
      $('#unit_cities').val(data.customer_site)
      $('#unit_sn').val(data.unit_sn)
      $('#unit_brand').val(data.unit_brand)
      $('#unit_type').val(data.unit_type)
      $('#unit_model').val(data.unit_model)
    },
    error: function() {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="{{route('ticket-service/store')}}" method="POST" id="main_form">
  @csrf
  <div class="panel panel-inverse">
    <div class="panel-heading ui-sortable-handle">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Ticket Service Create</h4>
      
      <div class="panel-heading-btn">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-warning" data-click="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket_inquiry_from"><b>Inquiry From</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            
            <select class="form-control ticket_inquiry_from form-control-sm" name="ticket_inquiry_from" id="ticket_inquiry_from">
              <option value="">Select Option</option>
              <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
              <option value="Website">Website</option>
              <option value="WhatsApp">WhatsApp</option>
              <option value="Email">Email</option>
            </select>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text ticket_inquiry_from_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket_inquiry_to"><b>Inquiry To</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            
            <select class="form-control ticket_inquiry_to form-control-sm" name="ticket_inquiry_to" id="ticket_inquiry_to">
              <option value="">Select Option</option>
              <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
              <option value="Service">Service</option>
              <option value="Sparepart">Sparepart</option>
            </select>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text ticket_inquiry_to_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket_inquiry_pic"><b>Inquiry PIC</b><a class="text-danger"> *</a></label>
            
            <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" class="form-control form-control-sm form-select form-select-sm" name="ticket_inquiry_pic[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%;">
              @foreach(SiteHelpers::get_user_all() as $pic)
              <option value="{{$pic->id}}" <?php echo (old( 'ticket_inquiry_pic')==$ pic->user_name) ? 'selected' : ''?>>{{$pic->user_name}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text ticket_inquiry_pic_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket_date"><b>Ticket Date</b></label>
            
            <div class="col-sm-13">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="ticket_date" value="{{date('Y/m/d')}}" readonly/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="service_request_date"><b>Service Request Date</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            
            <div class="col-sm-13">
              <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker-disabled-past" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-start-date="Date.default">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="service_request_date" value="{{old('service_request_date')}}" />
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
              </div>
              
              <span class="text-danger error-text service_request_date_error"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="liability_charges"><b>Charges To</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            
            <select class="form-control liability_charges form-control-sm" name="liability_charges" id="liability_charges">
              <option value="">Select Option</option>
              <option value="Principal">Principal</option>
              <option value="Dept. Marketing">Dept. Marketing</option>
              <option value="Dept. Part">Dept. Part</option>
              <option value="Dept. Service">Dept. Service</option>
              <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
              <option value="Free Charge">Free Charge</option>
            </select>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text liability_charges_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket_category"><b>Category</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            
            <select class="form-control category form-control-sm" name="ticket_category" id="ticket_category">
              <option value="">Select Category</option>
              <option value="Inspection">Inspection</option>
              <option value="Commissioning">Commissioning</option>
              <option value="Regular Service">Regular Service</option>
              <option value="Repair / Troubleshooting">Repair / Troubleshooting</option>
              <option value="Training">Training</option>
              <option value="Warranty">Warranty</option>
              <option value="Sparepart">Sparepart</option>
              <option value="Unit">Unit</option>
              <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text ticket_category_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="customer_id"><b>Customer</b><span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
            
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="hidden" id="customer_id" name="customer_id" value="{{(isset($data)) ? $data->customer_id : ''}}">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Customer Name" id="customer_name" href="{{route('population/popup_media')}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default" value="{{(isset($data)) ? $data->customer_name : ''}}">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span style="cursor:pointer;" class="input-group-text form-control-sm" href="#modal-new-customer" id='new-customer' rel='tooltip' data-placement='top' data-toggle='modal' title='Add New Customer'><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp<b>New</b></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text customer_id_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="customer_pic"><b>Customer PIC</b><span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="customer_pic" name="customer_pic" placeholder="Customer PIC">
            <span class="text-danger error-text customer_pic_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="customer_phone"><b>Customer Phone</b><span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="customer_phone" name="customer_phone" placeholder="Customer Phone">
            <span class="text-danger error-text customer_phone_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="customer_email"><b>Customer Email</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="customer_email" name="customer_email" placeholder="Customer Email">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="unit_sn"><b>Unit SN</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="unit_sn" name="unit_sn" placeholder="Unit SN" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="unit_brand"><b>Unit Brand</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="unit_brand" name="unit_brand" placeholder="Unit Brand" disabled>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category"><b>Unit Type</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="category" name="category" placeholder="Type" disabled>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="unit_model"><b>Unit Model</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="unit_model" name="unit_model" placeholder="Unit Model" disabled>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="province_name"><b>Unit Province</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm province_name" name="unit_province" id="unit_province">
              <option value="" disabled="true" selected="true">Choose Province</option>
              @foreach(SiteHelpers::get_province() as $province)
              <option value="{{$province->id}}">{{$province->province_name}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text unit_province_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cities"><b>Unit City</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm cities" name="unit_cities" id="unit_cities">
              <option value="0" disabled selected>Select City</option>
            </select>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text unit_cities_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="unit_site"><b>Site/Workshop Address</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="unit_site" name="unit_site" placeholder="Unit Site">
            <span class="text-danger error-text unit_site_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="unit_status"><b>Unit Status</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            
            <select class="form-control category form-control-sm" name="unit_status" id="unit_status">
              <option value="">Select Status</option>
              <option value="Breakdown">Breakdown</option>
              <option value="Stand By">Running</option>
              <option value="Working">Stand By</option>
            </select>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text unit_status_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket_complaints"><b>Informed Issue</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <textarea name="ticket_complaints" id="ticket_complaints" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="height: 99px;"></textarea>
            <span class="text-danger error-text ticket_complaints_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket_notes"><b>Notes</b></label>
            <textarea name="ticket_notes" id="ticket_notes" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="height: 99px;"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket_status"><b>Ticket Status</b> </label>
            
            <select class="form-control category form-control-sm" name="ticket_status" id="ticket_status">
              <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
              <option value="Finished">Finished</option>
            </select>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text ticket_status_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3 ticket-detail" style="display:none;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket_guidance"><b>Ticket Guidance</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            
            <select class="form-control category form-control-sm" name="ticket_guidance" id="ticket_guidance">
              <option value="">Select Guidance</option>
              <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
              <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
            
            <span class="text-danger error-text ticket_guidance_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-6 ticket-detail" style="display:none;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticket_guide_name"><b>Guide Name</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="ticket_guide_name" id="ticket_guide_name" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <span class="text-danger error-text ticket_guide_name_error"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success m-r-5">Submit</button>
      <a href="{{route('ticket-service/index')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse m-r-5">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- the modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-new-customer" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Customer</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      
      <form action="{{ route('customer/storeWithPopulation') }}" method="POST" id="main_form2">
        @csrf
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <label for="unit"><b><i>Customer(s)</i></b></label>
            
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="customer_name"><b>Customer Name</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="temp">
                  <input type="hidden" name="unit_status_stock" value="DELIVERED">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_name" name="customer_name" placeholder="Customer Name" value="{{old('customer_name')}}">
                  <span class="text-danger error-text customer_name_error"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="PIC"><b>PIC</b></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_pic" name="customer_pic" placeholder="PIC" value="{{old('customer_pic')}}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="province_name"><b>Unit Province</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  
                  <select class="form-control province_name" name="customer_province" id="customer_province">
                    <option value="" disabled="true" selected="true">Choose Province</option>
                    @foreach(SiteHelpers::get_province() as $province)
                    <option value="{{$province->id}}">{{$province->province_name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                  
                  <span class="text-danger error-text customer_province_error"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="cities"><b>Site</b> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  
                  <select class="form-control cities" name="customer_site" id="customer_site">
                    <option value="0" disabled selected>Select City</option>
                  </select>
                  
                  <span class="text-danger error-text customer_site_error"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            </br>
            
            <label for="unit"><b><i>Population(s)</i></b></label>
            
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="brand"><b>Brand</b><span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
                  
                  <select class="form-control brand form-control-sm" name="unit_brand" id="unit_brand">
                    <option value="">Chose Brand</option>
                    @foreach($brands as $brand)
                    <option value="{{$brand->brand}}">{{$brand->brand}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                  
                  <span class="text-danger error-text unit_brand_error"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="model"><b>Category</b><span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
                  
                  <select class="form-control category form-control-sm" name="unit_category" id="unit_category">
                    <option value="" disabled>Select Category</option>
                  </select>
                  
                  <span class="text-danger error-text unit_category_error"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 tes">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="model"><b>Model</b><span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
                  
                  <select class="form-control model form-control-sm" name="unit_model" id="unit_model">
                    <option value="" disabled>Select Model</option>
                  </select>
                  
                  <span class="text-danger error-text unit_model_error"></span>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="serial_number"><b>Serial Number</b><span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="unit_sn" name="unit_sn" placeholder="Unit Serial Number">
                  <span class="text-danger error-text unit_sn_error"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="year"><b>Unit Year</b><span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="unit_year" name="unit_year" placeholder="Unit Year">
                  <span class="text-danger error-text unit_year_error"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#cccccc;">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's my Controller :

```
public function storeWithPopulation(Request $request){
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('master-customer-create'),403);
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),Customer::$createRules,Customer::$customMessage);
    $validator2 = Validator::make($request->all(),Population::$createRules,Population::$customMessage);
    if(!$validator->passes() && !$validator2->passes()){
        $errors = array_merge($validator->errors()->toArray(),$validator2->errors()->toArray());
        return response()->json(['status'=>0, 'error'=>$errors]);
    }else{
        $last_id = Customer::all()->last();
        $customer_id = 'CUST-'.$last_id->id;
        $values_customer = [
            'customer_id'=>$customer_id,
            'customer_name'=>$request->customer_name,
            'customer_pic'=>$request->customer_pic,
            'customer_site'=>$request->customer_site,
            'customer_province'=>$request->customer_province,
        ];
        $values_population = [
            'customer_id' => $customer_id,
            'unit_model'=>$request->unit_model,
            'unit_sn'=>$request->unit_sn,
            'unit_year'=>$request->unit_year,
            'unit_status_stock'=>$request->unit_status_stock,
        ];
        
        $new_customer = Customer::create($values_customer);
        $new_population = Population::create($values_population);

        if( $new_population ){
            $brands = DB::table('t_brand')->get();
            $data = SiteHelpers::get_population_by_sn($new_population->unit_sn);

            return response()->json(['status'=>1, 'url'=>'/service/forms/ticket-service/create',['data'=>$data,'brands'=>$brands]]);
            // return response()->json(['status'=>1, 'url'=>'/service/forms/ticket-service/create',['data'=>$data,'brands'=>$brands]]);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, everytime I succeeded create new customer in the modal it also redirect into the main form,but got refreshed and the main form completely in blank condition. I want to grab all the new customer I've just inputed into the main form.

hopefully somebody can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You wrote very well, what you try to achieve, but nothing about, what is not working or if there is an error message...

Comment: @biberman sorry my bad, I edited my question aboce. thank you sir.

Comment: Has nothing to do with Laravel, so maybe change your title?

Comment: @bart I'm working this issue in Laravel, that's why I put Laravel in my title. I wondering if I do wrong in controller or my blade file.

Comment: You don't show any PHP code at all...